# how to use tilt action on iDevice to move sprite in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

Im developing a game and I'm trying to figure out a way to use the iDevice's tilt function to move the sprite. As in if I want the sprite to move to the left i'd tilt my iDevice to the left. I used this code, however sometimes it isn't responsive.

```
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var destX:CGFloat  = 0.0
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler:{
            data, error in
            let currentX = self.steve.position.x
            if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 500)
                //self.rolling = true
                //self.steve.removeAllActions()
                self.steve.runAction(rotate)
            }
            else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 500)
                //self.rolling = true
               // self.steve.removeAllActions()
                self.steve.runAction(rerotate())
            }
        })
    }
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.9)
        steve.runAction(action)
    }
```